# about the complex number

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots, factoring, cubics

Let $a+ ib$ be the complex root of $f(x)=x^3+2x+1$.
I want to find $a$.

My Try: $f(a+ib)=0$. It follow that
$$(a^3-3ab^2+2a+1)=(-b^3+3a^2b+2b)=0$$

Comment: Expand $f(a+ib)=0$ and look at the real part.

Comment: i want the value of $a$

Comment: From equating $f(a+ib)=f(a-ib)$ we get $1-4a-8a^3=0$, which doesn't look promising.

Comment: $a+ib$ is a root $\implies -2a$ is the real root, so $f(-2a)=0$ gives the cubic you need to solve for $a$.  As pointed out in earlier comments, that doesn't look promising.  Are you sure the cubic in question is reproduced accurately?  Where is this problem from?

Comment: why $f(-2a)=0$?

Comment: @Littlegirl Complex roots are found in conjugate pairs for real polynomials, and further by Vieta, the sum of all three roots is zero in this case. Hence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it means $a$ and $b$ are reals.

If so, $x^3+2x+1$ is divisible by $$(x-a-bi)(x-a+bi)=x^2-2ax+a^2+b^2,$$ which is possible for the following factoring only.
$$x^3+2x+1=(x+2a)(x^2-2ax+a^2+b^2),$$
which says that $a=-\frac{1}{2}x_1$, where $x_1$ is a real root of the polynomial $x^3+2x+1$.

Now, use the Cardano's formula:
$$x_1=\sqrt[3]{-\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{8}{27}}}+\sqrt[3]{-\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{8}{27}}}=...$$